# Cannot cancel fileDownloadTask on cancel Button click

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am downloading many images from firebase one by one by `download()` function with the progress dialog. For that, I made on the list of `FileDownloadTask`. Now I want to cancel the download for remaining images on cancel button click for that I implemented the method in `OnClickListener` as shown in the code but It won't work and images are going to continue downloading.

```
List<FileDownloadTask> downloadTaskList = new ArrayList<>();
protected void download() throws IOException, JSONException {
        setDownloadProgressDialoag();
        imageList = image.getImages();
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "Images");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        for (Image image : imageList) {
            String url = image.getImageUrl();
            File imageFile = new File(file, i + "_" + image.getName() + ".jpg");
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                downloadRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(url);
                    FileDownloadTask task = downloadRef.getFile(imageFile);
                    downloadTaskList.add(task);
                    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            downloadProgressDialoag.incrementProgressBy(1);
                            downloadTaskList.remove(task);
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
                    i++;
                }
        }
}
```

ProgressDialog

```
private void setDownloadProgressDialoag() {
        downloadProgressDialoag = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.PackLoaderDialog);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setTitle("Downloading Images...");
        downloadProgressDialoag.setMax(Image.noOfImage);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setCancelable(false);
        downloadProgressDialoag.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                for(FileDownloadTask fileDownloadTask : downloadTaskList){
                    fileDownloadTask.cancel();
                }
            }
        });
        downloadProgressDialoag.show();
    }
```

What thing I am doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Do you have an error or?

Comment: No, I am not getting an error but when I check in FileManager after canceling all files shows downloaded. @AlexMamo

Comment: Are you downloading a significant number of files? How are you ensuring that your cancels trigger before all the files are downloaded?  I would recommending adding an onCancel listener and making sure it gets invoked.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me what should I have to add in `OnCancelListener `? I have added `task.cancel` but it doesn't work. Images are still continuing the download. @Naveed

Comment: You can simply add a log statement in your OnCancel() and log the file name for something whatever got cancelled. Something like `"Task canceled for: " + imageFile.getName()`.  Also I recreated your case and  the cancel is working as  expected. My guess is that you  are not downloading enough data so the files are getting downloaded before you get a chance to hit cancel. Another thing to note is that you are creating a new task for each file and several tasks may execute at the same time. So even if you call cancel, a task that is already running will still finish.